# What will be set builder notation for this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Following set is neither of even nor of odd so how can I express this by using set builder notation?

```
{0,3,6,9,12}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there already **is** a form of set builder notation. If you’re asking how you can express it in set builder notation using some property or properties of the numbers in the set, notice that they are the multiples of $3$ between $0$ and $12$, inclusive:

$$\{0,3,6,9,12\}=\{n\in\Bbb N:n\le 12\text{ and }3\mid n\}\;,$$

where $3\mid n$ means that $n$ is a multiple of $3$, in case you’re not familiar with that notation. Another possibility is

$$\big\{3k:k\in\{0,1,2,3,4\}\big\}\;;$$

yet another is

$$\{n\in\Bbb N:\exists k\in\Bbb N(n=3k)\text{ and }n\le 12\}\;.$$

Comment: Yet another is $$\{ x \in \mathbb{R} : x^5-30x^4+315x^3-1350x^2+1944x = 0 \}$$ (I didn't think this was worth its own answer so I hope you don't mind posting it as a comment.)

Comment: @Clive: $\large\overset{\otimes\otimes}\smile$

Answer (score -1):

You can also write it in this way: $\{\; 3x \;|\; x = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 \;\}$.